# How do I read a text file of numbers into an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, opencv3.0, polyline

In python, using the OpenCV library, I need to create some polylines. The example code for the polylines method shows:

```
 cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(0,255,255))
```

I have all the 'pts' laid out in a text file in the format:

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4
```

How can I read this file and provide the data to the [pts] variable in the method call?

I've tried the np.array(csv.reader(...)) method as well as a few others I've found examples of. I can successfully read the file, but it's not in the format the polylines method wants. (I am a newbie when it comes to python, if this was C++ or Java, it wouldn't be a problem).

Comment: If ``pts = np.array(csv.read(...))``, then you're just doing ``cv2.polylines(img, pts, ...)``, right?

Comment: Well, yes. But it doesn't work. I get 'TypeError: pts' when running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not pretty and there is probably a MUCH BETTER way to do this, but it works. That being said, if someone could show me a better way, it would be much appreciated.

```
pointlist = []
f = open(args["slots"])
data = f.read().split()
for row in data:
    tmp = []
    col = row.split(";")
    for points in col:
        xy = points.split(",")
        tmp += [[int(pt) for pt in xy]]
    pointlist += [tmp]

slots = np.asarray(pointlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use numpy to read the csv as an array.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
p = genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=',')

cv2.polylines(img,p,True,(0,255,255))
```

You may have to pass a dtype argument to the genfromtext if you need to coerce the data to a specific format.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: That will read in the numbers but 'p' is not in the correct format. The format must be [[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]

Answer (score 0):

In case you know it is a fixed number of items in each row:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
    res = list(zip(*rows))
    print(res)
```

Comment: It is a fixed number of items (4 sets of x,y coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to draw each polyline individually (to expand on @Chris's answer):

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
lines = genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=',')

for line in lines:
    cv2.polylines(img, line.reshape((-1, 2)), True, (0,255,255))
```